# Is the matrix in "View.getMatrix" and in "Animation transformation" the same thing?

Tags: android, animation, matrix, view, transformation

Got some confusions about Android View's matrix and animations:

**Background:**

(1) Matrix1: The matrix in animation transformation can be applied to the view to implement an animation:

```
public class myAnimation extends Animation {
  public myAnimation() { }

  @Override
  boolean   willChangeTransformationMatrix() { return true; }

  @Override
  void  applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    Matrix m = t.getMatrix();
    // do whatever you want to the matrix here, using the interpolatedTime
  }
}
```

(2) Matrix2: On post Honeycomb Android, you should be able to do similar things just by manipulating the matrix on a view though:

```
Matrix m = view.getMatrix();
// do whatever you want here
```

Of course, you can also change the matrix in "View.getMatrix" through view.setScale or view.setRotation.

**Questions:**

(1) Are these two matrices the same thing? If an animation is applied to the view and setFillAfter is set to be true, would the animation matrix change the result of View.getMatrix?

(2) As I know, all animations don't really change the view layout, only the way it is shown.(You can use a button and setOnClickListener for it , and see that no matter which animation you use , the click will work only on its original position and size). So, does "view.setScale"、"view.setTranslation" and "view.setRotation" work the same way?

(3) In the API reference, it says about View.getMatrix : "The transform matrix of this view, which is calculated based on the current roation, scale, and pivot properties." Why is the "translation property" not included in this matrix?

By the way, what I really want to do is to calculate positions in parents' coordinate when given in descendant's coordinate.

Don't have to answer all the questions in your reply. Any opinions related to the subject are appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Allen, what's your requirements exactly? can you please tell me?

Comment: What I really want to do is to calculate positions in parents' coordinate when given in descendant's coordinate. Say, if I touch a view and I can get the event position in this view's coordinate through the view's onTouch(). And now I want to calculate this position in the parent's coordinate. Given this view and its parent might be animated or scaled, I have to consider the animation matrix and the "intrinsic matrix" --- the one given by view.getMatrix().